# Assign task email not sent unless it is user who created the item

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have set a workflow that when the assigned to field is filled in the user should get an email. This doesn't happen unless it's the user who create the item. I only want the user to see their own items they create as they are HR support requests then I want anyone in the HR admin to be able to assign as tasks but this won't happen. Any ideas I would be really greatful.